# Adding suffix text to price in WooCommerce cart and checkout page based on product category?

Tags: woocommerce, product, categories, suffix

I need to add a suffix text to the price of a woocommerce product while on WooCommerce cart.

Based on [How to add suffix text to price in WooCommerce cart and checkout page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888575/how-to-add-suffix-text-to-price-in-woocommerce-cart-and-checkout-page/43888748#43888748) answer, so I'm trying to adapt that code to recognize product categories.

I am also using `has_product_categories()` custom conditional function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54048257/3730754).

Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'kd_custom_price_message' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'kd_custom_price_message' );  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'kd_custom_price_message' );  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_total', 'kd_custom_price_message' ); 
function kd_custom_price_message( $price ) {

    if( is_cart() && has_product_categories( '46' ) ){
        $afterPriceSymbol = ' Monthly';
        return $price . $afterPriceSymbol;
        } else {
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Sadly I keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function has_product_categories()
```

I haven't been able to either combine the two (as in including the suffix one here) or adapt this one to the suffix text one.

Any clue what I'm missing?

Comment: The custom function `has_product_categories()`requires 2 arguments to be passed in. You are just passing the product ID in it but you need to pass also the targeted product categories terms in it a second argument.